# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - Right-click to SELECT TOP 1000 ROWS not available. Properties option not available when right-clicking a login

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I have just moved from SSMS 2008 to SSMS 2012. In 2012, I can not right-click on a table and "select top 1000 rows", nor can I "edit top 200 rows". This is despite having the valid settings in 'Tools -- Options -- SQL Server Object Explorer'.
(Value for Edit top  Rows command = 200. Value for Select Top  Rows command = 1000)

Furthermore, when attempting to choose a default database for a login, when I go to 'Security -- Logins' and right-click on my user, there is no "Properties" option available.

I have looked for a long time and no one else seems to have had this problem.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: _Did you follow prerequisites before installing_?

Comment: So what happens when you right click on a table? You see the short cut menu still but those options are missing?

Comment: When I right-click on a table I get four options pop up : 1-New Table 2-Filter 3-Reports 4-Refresh

Comment: @JohnLowry - Strange. The "filter" option should only show up on folders. Not when selecting a specific item. Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Someone else installed the program so I am not sure of the prerequisites done during installation. Is there any way I can check what these settings are? If not I will try a reinstallation.